# Are coinciding lines parallel?

Tags: geometry

I have a question about parallel lines and coincident lines. According to wikipedia a parallel line is:

> Two lines in a plane that do not intersect or touch at a point are
>   called parallel lines.

But another reference says

> Side by side and having the same distance continuously between them.

And two coincident lines follow each of the given two conditions i.e. they do not intersect at **a** point (as they intersect in more than one point) and also the distance between them remians same.
So are two coinciding lines parallel or am I missing something.

Comment: See also the post : [In classical geometry why is a line considered to be parallel to itself ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742126/in-classical-geometry-why-is-a-line-considered-to-be-parallel-to-itself)

Comment: The level of duplication in this question to [a previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411249/what-is-a-parallel-line) is remarkable. It's hard to believe that this is coincidental. If you saw that question and were not satisfied with the answers, you could/should revise your own question to *reference* the other one, and ask for responses that address specific points you need clarified.

Comment: @TheMathemagician  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, as trivial case, two coinciding lines are parallel in the sense that, with reference to the parametric equation, their direction vectors $v$ and $w$ are parallel

- $L_1: P_1+t\,v$
- $L_2: P_2+t\, w$

with $v\parallel w$ and $P_1\in L_2$.